# Get cursor parent in editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a content editable div which looks like this:

```
<div class="note" contenteditable="true">
   ABCD
   <div class="first">EFGH</div>
   <div class="second">IJKL</div>
   MNOP
</div>
```

So this makes the whole code editable. What I need to find out is, on every keypress, which element contains the cursor. So if the cursor is right after `E`, it should result the div with class `first`.

I tried using `focus()` event on the child divs, but it doesn't get fired when the parent is `contenteditable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the element the caret (blinking text cursor) is currently in:

```
let caretElement = document.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode;
```

Here's an example which highlights that element as you move around:

```js
setInterval(()=>{
  let marked = document.querySelector(".marked");
  if (marked) {
      marked.classList.remove("marked");
  }
  
  let currentElement = document.getSelection().anchorNode;
  if (currentElement) {
    currentElement.parentNode.classList.add("marked");
  }
},200);
```

```css
.marked {
  background-color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="note" contenteditable="true">
   ABCD
   <div class="first">EFGH</div>
   <div class="second">IJKL</div>
   MNOP
</div>
```